# Lazy binding of method call in Python

Tags: python

Suppose, i have a class named `A` and it has one method called `method_one`. Say, i am converting a dict having the name of the method `method_one` as value, `method` as key and converting it to JSON for some reason (Amazon SQS).

Now when i convert back the JSON string to dict (reading from Amazon SQS), after pulling out the method name using dict syntax and then calling the method on the class object returns error.

```
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'method'
```

How to call the method on the class's object?

```
import json


class A:
    def method_one(self):
        return "method_one"


j_json = json.dumps({
    'method': A.method_one.__name__
})

j_dict = json.loads(j_json)

a = A()
method = j_dict['method']
a.method()
```

Answer (score 3):

`method` variable has the actual method to be invoked's name, not the actual method itself. You need to get the method corresponding to the name in `method` variable, with `getattr` function and invoke it like this

```
>>> import json
>>> class A:
...     def method_one(self):
...         return "method_one"
... 
>>> j_json = json.dumps({
...     'method': A.method_one.__name__
... })
>>> j_dict = json.loads(j_json)
>>> a = A()
>>> method = j_dict['method']
>>> getattr(a, method)()
'method_one'
```